# Mockito mock method call that accepts generic class as argument

Tags: java, mockito

I have a Java class `ResourceProvider`

```
public abstract ResourceProvider {
   public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle();
}
```

which is extended by ResourceProviderDao and ResourceProviderFoo (both have similar implementation as below)

```
public class ResourceProviderDao extends ResourceProvider {
    
    private DaoResource daoResource;

    public ResourceProviderDao(final Context context) {
        final ResourceSpec<DaoResource> spec = ModeledResourceSpec.builder(DaoResource.class).name("DaoResource").build();
        this.daoResource = context.getResource(spec);
    }

    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle() {
        return daoResource.getResourceBundle();
    }
}
```

`Context` has following method signature:

```
public Resource getResource(ResourceSpec<T> spec);
```

I have following spec instances:

```
ResourceSpec<DaoResource>
ResourceSpec<FooResource>
```

I have a `ResourceProviderMap` class:

```
public class ResourceProviderMap {
    private static HashMap<String, ResourceProvider> resourceProviderMap = new HashMap<>();

    public ResourceProviderMap(final Context context) {
        resourceProviderMap.put("content.dao", new ResourceProviderDao(context));
        resourceProviderMap.put("content.foo", new ResourceProviderFoo(context));

    }
    public ResourceProvider getResourceProvider(String resourceType) {
        return resourceProviderMap.get(resourceType);
    }
}
```

I want to write unit test for `ResourceProviderMap`. Since it creates ResourceProviderDao and ResourceProviderFoo instances, it needs to invoke `context.getResource(spec)`.

Question: How do I mock the `getResource` method call? Something like below:

```
@Mock
private Context mockContext;

// this syntax doesn't work
when(mockContext.getResource(any(ResourceSpec<DaoResource>.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResourceDao);
when(mockContext.getResource(any(ResourceSpec<FooResource>.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResourceFoo);
```

I tried using ArgumentMatchers:

```
when(mockContext.getResource(ArgumentMatchers.<ResourceSpec<DaoResource>>any()))
    .thenReturn(mockResourceDao);

when(mockContext.getResource(ArgumentMatchers.<ResourceSpec<FooResource>>any()))
    .thenReturn(mockResourceFoo);
```

but the second mock overrides the first mock, I'm guessing because of `any()`. Could anyone help how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what is your actual test case you could just use instances of `ResourceSpec`  - and perhaps mock these instances - instead trying to match generic types. I believe type erasure gives Mockito hard times to determine what stubbing to use (*so it just uses the first in list or so*).

Also use `doReturn(..).when(..).getResource(..)` instead of `when().thenReturn(..)` because the latter way seems to mix Mockito a bit and it complains about possible bad stubbing. Alternatively you could make stubbings *lenient* so  `lenient().when(..)...` but prefer the `doReturn(..)...` syntax so that Mockito is still able to detect other possible mistakes in stubbing. And as an example how I would make it:

```
@Mock
private Resource mockResourceFoo;
@Mock
private Resource mockResourceDao;
@Mock
private Context mockContext;
// Your spec instances. could also be @Mock
private ResourceSpec<FooResource> resourceSpecFoo = new ResourceSpec<>();
private ResourceSpec<DaoResource> resourceSpecDao = new ResourceSpec<>();

@Test
public void test() {
    doReturn(mockResourceFoo).when(mockContext).getResource(resourceSpecFoo);
    doReturn(mockResourceDao).when(mockContext).getResource(resourceSpecDao);
    assertEquals(mockResourceFoo, mockContext.getResource(resourceSpecFoo));
    assertEquals(mockResourceDao, mockContext.getResource(resourceSpecDao));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the argument passed to ```getResource``` is constructed in the method under test itself, so I can't mock it or use instance of it. Is there no way to type-match with ArgumentMatchers? I was wondering something like type matching in any() construct would work but this syntax doesn't work - ```when(mockContext.getResource(ArgumentMatchers.<ResourceSpec<FooResource>>any(ResourceSpec<FooResource>.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResourceFoo) ```

Comment: You might want to expose all the relevant code in your question like `getResource(..)`? I did not quite understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I added details in the question around what I'm trying to do. Basically I don't have access to ```Context.getResource(..)``` argument directly.